# In F#, is there a built-in function that returns a function returning a given value when invoked with no arguments?

Tags: f#

In F#, is there a built-in function that returns a function returning a given value when invoked with no arguments?

That is, a function with the following, or equivalent, definition:

```
let ret v =
    fun () -> v
```

Comment: Looks a bit like `const` in Haskell. There's nothing built-in to F# for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, an equivalent to Haskell's [`const`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/src/GHC-Base.html#const)? No, there is no such function in the standard library. But you can define it like you just did if you need it often.

Comment: Yes, that's right. It was more like a curiosity question. And I was going to add a comment asking about other functional languages, so thanks for the pointer :-)